# Linux C program: waitpid() with options=WEXITED, why fail with EINVAL?

Tags: linux, waitpid

I have a small program `waitpidx.cpp`:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid != 0)
    {
        printf("Parent process: getpid()=%d\n", (int)getpid());

        int wstatus = 0;
        int waitflags = WEXITED; // 0 is OK, but WEXITED not OK.
        pid_t wpid = waitpid(child_pid, &wstatus, waitflags);
        if (wpid == -1)
        {
            printf("waitpid() fail. errno=%d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(4);
        }
        assert(wpid == child_pid);
        printf("Parent process waitpid(,,%d) success.\n", waitflags);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Child process

    printf("Child  process: getpid()=%d\n", (int)getpid());
    sleep(1);
}
```

Running it on Ubuntu Linux 20.04 and 22.04, `waitpid()` fails with `EINVAL(22)`.

[image]

In order for `waitpid()` to succeed, I need to set `waitflags=0`.

Why is it so? The `man waitpid` says:

> `WEXITED`     Wait for children that have terminated.

Then I think `waitflags=0` and `waitflags=WEXITED` should have the same meaning.

What's wrong with using `WEXITED`, and what is its correct use case?

Comment: Please copy-and-paste from your terminal _as text_. Screenshots aren't searchable, are incompatible with accessibility tools, can't be copied/pasted from, &c (as discussed in [Why not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122).

Comment: Speaking to content as opposed to form -- are you sure WEXITED is valid for `waitpid`, as opposed to only for the newer `waitid`? My read of the manual is the latter (if you're looking at the same man page I am, the single page covers all three of `wait`, `waitpid` and `waitid`).

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I check `man waitpid` again, the `WEXITED` is really valid only for `waitid`.

Comment: Great; adding that as an answer proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy mistake to make since a single man page covers all three of `wait()`, `waitpid()`, and `waitid()` -- but `WEXITED` is only valid in the newer syscall `waitid`, not in `waitpid`.